# Ionic page redirect not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

App component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Config, Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = HomePage;

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  pages: any[] = [
    { title: 'HomePage', component: 'HomePage' },
    { title: 'CategoriesPage', component: 'CategoriesPage' },
    { title: 'SubCategoriesPage', component: 'SubCategoriesPage' },
    { title: 'ChangepasswordPage', component: 'ChangepasswordPage' },
    { title: 'LoginPage', component: 'LoginPage' },
    { title: 'ForgotpasswordPage', component: 'ForgotpasswordPage' },
    { title: 'SignupPage', component: 'SignupPage' },
    { title: 'TabsPage', component: 'TabsPage' }
  ]

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

}
```

App module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule, IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Page:

```
<ion-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col text-center>
        <p color="secondary" style="text-align: center;">Not registered? <b (click)="openPage(HomePage)">Create an account</b></p>
        <p color="secondary" style="text-align: center;">Login? <b (click)="openPage()">Click here</b></p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

The homepage is visible but another page is not opening. In the component page, there is an open page function but still it not working. Anyone can please tell why other pages are not opening and How can I resolve this issue? Sorry for my weak English. I am a beginner in ionic so please try to explain in-depth. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a sidebar menu? which function are you calling and what page do you want to navigate to and  you are using two functions one with page parameter and one without parameter

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to your variable

```
pages: any[] = [
    { title: 'HomePage', component: 'HomePage' },
    { title: 'CategoriesPage', component: 'CategoriesPage' },
    { title: 'SubCategoriesPage', component: 'SubCategoriesPage' },
    { title: 'ChangepasswordPage', component: 'ChangepasswordPage' },
    { title: 'LoginPage', component: 'LoginPage' },
    { title: 'ForgotpasswordPage', component: 'ForgotpasswordPage' },
    { title: 'SignupPage', component: 'SignupPage' },
    { title: 'TabsPage', component: 'TabsPage' }
  ]
```

As you can see it's an array. It contains multiple pages. So when you want to use page you need to specify which one. For example if I want to go to **CategoriesPage** this what I would do, based on your array.

- Change your button in html to return the page you want to go

  (click)="openPage('LoginPage')">Click here
- Go through the array of pages & select the page you want to go to

  openPage(page) {
          this.pages.forEach(_page => if (_page.title == page) this.nav.setRoot(page.component));
        }